# How can i remove this message from my terminal?

Tags: ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I had ROS 1(noetic) on my Ubuntu. Then i removed it and installed ROS 2. But whenever i open the terminal, i see this message and i don't know how to remove it. Could you help me with that? Thanks

```
bash: /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409496/how-can-i-remove-this-message-from-my-terminal?/) by [whxper](https://answers.ros.org/users/124054/whxper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. This message's origin is ~/.bashrc file. You should type:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

After that go to the bottom and you will see

```
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

Delete this line of code. Then the message won't appear anymore.

---

Originally posted by [whxper](https://answers.ros.org/users/124054/whxper/) with karma: 16 on 2022-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0